# No XHProf runs specified in the URL

Tags: drupal-6, xhprof

I have configured XHProf on linux server but on accessing xhprof_html/index.php, instead of displaying logged slow queries, it just displays this "No XHProf runs specified in the URL." What does this refer to?

Comment: This is a duplicate (by the same user) and has already been answered elsewhere.
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19193/how-to-configure-xhprof-for-drupal-6-on-windows

Comment: @JosepValls That question does not seem related to me.

Comment: @mattalxndr Actually, I previously had an answer to this question to which the asker himself sidra-sultana had replied acknowledging the question duplication but that answer was deleted by bill-the-lizard and now I'm not sure why is this question still up. Do you want to go ahead and flag this question for removal?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you were trying to reach the `index.php` file with `?run=` query parameter set to something.

In order to really list the runs, it should be accessed **without any arguments**. The profiling files are usually stored in the system temporary directory, usually `/tmp` on Linux.